# I'm having trouble resolving a Internship postgresql exercise. Using two different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've applied myself for a internship which uses postgresql, I never had any contact with programming language before the university which started just a couple months ago. The employer sent me an email with some exercises that I have to do before Monday. I have three days to learn the language and resolve the exercises. I've been studying the whole day, about 14 hours (for real). I'm getting used to the postgresql but I'm struggling with one thing. Since I'm very new to programming and I don't have enough time to do that very specific  search I have no other options but ask you guys for.

Here's the problem. I have the same columns 'id_cliente' on both tables. I need to show a table where it shows all persons names, ids and how many movies each one of them borrowed from the rental.

I tried two different codes and none of them works.

```
select en_cliente.id_cliente, nome, count(en_aluguel.id_cliente) as alugueis
from en_cliente, en_aluguel
where en_cliente.id_cliente=en_aluguel.id_cliente
group by en_cliente.id_cliente;
```

Which makes Maria goes missing (Because her ID doesn't shows at the first table. It's supposed to show a zero

Also:

```
select en_cliente.id_cliente, nome, count(en_aluguel.id_cliente) as alugueis
from en_cliente, en_aluguel
group by en_cliente.id_cliente;
```

Which makes every value of the last column (id as alugueis) to be a '7'

First Table:
[image: First Table]

Second Table:
[image: Second Table]

Third Table:
[image: Final Result]

Comment: Hi Jonas, all the text about your position in live and hardships are frowned upon here.Its considered _noise_. Talk to your future employer about your problem to solve this task - if he does not give you enough time to  learn on the job what you need to know when filling this position you wont get happy there.  You might want to google for outer joins which could help you solve this. If you provide SQL question, consider providing a SQL-fiddle [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/) filled with tables and data already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Any time you have two tables in the FROM line, you’re doing an INNER JOIN, which requires matching rows on both tables.
2. Any time you have criteria in the WHERE clause, only rows matching that will be returned, which again will limit you to records in both tables with the clause you have.

You need to LEFT JOIN, which allows you to go from records that exist, to records that may or may not exist.

Give this a try. It will start at your en_cliente table and will join to your records in the en_aluguel table even if there is not a match in en_aluguel.

```
select en_cliente.id_cliente, nome, count(en_aluguel.id_cliente) as alugueis
from en_cliente
left join en_aluguel on (en_cliente.id_cliente=en_aluguel.id_cliente)
group by en_cliente.id_cliente;
```

Note: if you change the word “left” in my example to “inner”, you’ll end up with exactly the same code (just a different syntax) as your first example.